# iFrame appears full-screen in phonegap. I only want it the height of its containing div

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

iFrame appears full-screen on my android phone.

```
<div>
<iframe src="iframe.html" id="iframesha" seamless></iframe>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix it? I have a div above this iFrame and its taking over the div!

Comment: Have you tried researching?

Comment: Yes. Still cant find the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Iframe has to have a width and height attributes See example below:

and link http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_iframe_width.asp

hope this helps